# browserify throwing error: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) while parsing file: image.png

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, webpack, browserify

This sounds absolutely ridiculous but I cannot, for the life of me, display an inline image in my angular project scaffolded by webpack. Every time I use a valid path to the image (in either the `<img>` tag or in my `require('/app/image.png')` I get the error:

> Unexpected character '�' (1:0) while parsing file: /app/image.png

I have tried using just about every image loader, file loader, static loader, etc. i've tried different images and different locations for those images. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my current image loader from webpack.config.js:

```
{
  test: /\.png$/, 
  loader: "url-loader?limit=8192"
}
```

I see all these reference to including the loader in the require statement like:

```
require("url?limit=10000!/app/image.png");
```

Anytime i try anything similar in my /app/scripts/main.js file, I get this error:

> Cannot find module 'url?limit=10000!/app/image.png' from '/Users/dmp/bidder-client/app/scripts'

I'm very confused :/

Comment: I think browserify doesn't supposed to parse images. I thought it is for parsing JS files so it can handle required statements

Answer (score -1):

if you add the new images or resources file into your project,you should Reinstall your app rather than just refresh js.
so,you should : react-native run-android